# API Designer on alternative browser

Tags: apiconnect

The command **apic edit** opens the API management on a browser. Is there any way to customize which browser it opens? Alternatively can I prevent it from opening any browser, and open something other than your default browser?

Comment: What version of `apiconnect` are you running?

Comment: API Connect: v5.0.4.0-iFix2 (apiconnect: v2.3.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the terribly slow reply.

> Is there any way to customize which browser it opens?

No, it opens the default OS browser.

> Alternatively can I prevent it from opening any browser

Yes. If you move up to `apic-v5.0.5.0` you can use the 'accessibility-mode' configuration option to not launch a browser.

`$ apic config:set accessibility-mode=enabled
accessibility-mode: enabled
$ apic edit
Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:9000
API Designer will now open in your default web browser. Press escape to cancel or any other key to continue.`

Comment: Upgraded to v5.0.5.0. Works for me. Thanks.